# hasNextInt() and nextInt() method flow

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How does this conditional statement (from Udacity's Intro to Java Programming | Problem Set 4 | Question #20) work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a month number (1 through 12) ");

        if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Not an integer. Terminating");
        } else {
            int theMonthNumber = in.nextInt();

            if (!(theMonthNumber >= 1 && theMonthNumber <= 12)) {
                System.out.println("Number must be 1 through 12");
            } else {
                Month test = new Month(theMonthNumber);
                System.out.print(test.getMonthName() + " " + test.getNumberOfDays());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first `if (!in.hasNextInt())` checks to see if the user input is an integer. If it's NOT an integer, the main method prints `Not an integer. Terminating`. That makes complete sense.

However, in the event that the user inputs an integer, the code proceeds to the `else` statement where the next line of code is `int theMonthNumber = in.nextInt();`

When the program runs and I provide an integer as an input, I'm NOT prompted for another input. I'm thinking that both the `hasNextInt()` method and `nextInt()` method should request an input from the user. Therefore, I should be prompted for a total of two inputs (assuming I provide an integer). When I dry-run this scenario, I input an integer 3. This passes the `if(!hasNextInt())` check.

What am I missing in the logical flow of the statement(s)?

Comment: Don't rely on what you're "thinking in your mind". Every class in Java has [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28int%29). It says exactly what the methods do. If it doesn't say it prompts the user for additional input, then that doesn't happen.

Comment: One method checks if an int is there and the other actually takes it. Plus, you don't have to guess or assume. All built in classes are open source.

Comment: `When the program runs and I provide an integer as an input, I'm NOT prompted for another input`. This is because you haven't programmed it to ask for a second input. Look into `loops`, or add more code to ask for another input.

Comment: I think I get it now. In this simplified code:

Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
  test.hasNextInt();

The test.hasNextInt(); prompts the user for an input and determines if returns a boolean based on the users' input.  I was confused because I misinterpreted what the documentation was saying and thought that the hasNextInt() method simply looks at the existing inputs rather than prompting the user (in this example) for an input and evaluating that.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking in my mind that both the hasNextInt() method and nextInt() method should request an input from the user.

**No.** The [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) Javadoc says (in part)

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

The last sentence is telling you that it **does not** consume the `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Function `hasNextInt()` is just for checking the input value. It will not consume the input. What happens is, it will advance the Scanner and check the data but after that it will go back to it's previous position. So technically, the position of Scanner has not changed. That's why it's not prompting for next input.

Only `nextInt()` will consume the data. Scanner will advance to the next position after calling this function.